# Formal power series rings and p-adic solenoids

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, formal-power-series

For any prime $p$, the ring of $p$-adic integers can be generated as the quotient of the formal power series ring $\Bbb Z[[x]]/(x-p)$. My questions:

- If we instead use $\Bbb Q[[x]]/(x-p)$, do we get the field of $p$-adic numbers?
- If we instead use $\Bbb R[[x]]/(x-p)$, do we get the $p$-adic solenoid?
- Is there any sensible interpretation of $\Bbb C[[x]]/(x-p)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very generally, if $R$ is a commutative ring and $f\in R[[x]]$, then $f$ is a unit iff the constant term of $f$ is a unit in $R$ (if the constant term is a unit, then you can build the coefficients of an inverse to $f$ one-by-one).  So if $p$ is a unit in $R$, then $x-p$ is a unit in $R[[x]]$, and $R[[x]]/(x-p)$ is the zero ring.

Note that if you instead took $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]/(x-p)$ and formally inverted $p$, then you would get the $p$-adic rationals.  The difference between that and $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]/(x-p)$ is that in $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ you can have a power series which has coefficients with unbounded powers of $p$ in the denominators.  Such a power series cannot be written as a power series with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ divided by any fixed power of $p$.  This is in fact exactly what happens with the inverse of $x-p$.

Comment: Thanks - is the solenoid related to the formal power series in any way then?

Comment: Not that I know of.  As far as I know, solenoids do not have any natural ring structure, which makes a connection to formal power series seem unlikely.